Can I skip GLIBCXX check when using an unsupported Alpine distro?
I'm developing a workspace that uses Alpine and Php 7.2 as it's main components. I have a Dockerfile that uses the php:7.2-fpm-alpine distro for that matter, it builds and composes normally when performing docker compose up -d, but when I try to open it in a Remote Container, the following error appears:

I browsed the net only to see my problem seems to be very poorly documented, the only relevant instance of my problem is the Visual Studio Code's official Github project that has the following file check-requirements-linux.sh. Obviously I could use another image, but it is imperative for it to be an Alpine distro (so anything that is php:7.2-<ALPINE DISTRO>), so I'd like to know if there is a  way to ignore this, either by skipping the script check, or any other way that makes work without worrying about it, something that suddenly closes the Dev Container and makes me unable to open it and program in.
A popular workaround to this problem (that works) is to downgrade the Visual Studio Code version to v.1.8.5, as mentioned in the Github thread, but it is wildly unpractical, and only a temporary solution.
If it helps, this is my current Dockerfile that I'm building (that builds without any problem).
Dockerfile
#USE this Dockerfile if you want to test the image
ARG PHP_VERSION=7.2
ARG PHP_IMAGE=php:${PHP_VERSION}-fpm-alpine3.12
ARG PHP_PHALCON_VERSION=3.4.x
ARG PHP_COMPOSER_VERSION=2.1.8
ARG COMPOSER_IMAGE=composer:${PHP_COMPOSER_VERSION}
ARG AMQP_VERSION=amqp-1.10.2
ARG PHP_XDEBUG_VERSION=xdebug-3.1.0

FROM ${PHP_IMAGE} AS php
ARG AMQP_VERSION
ARG PHP_PHALCON_VERSION
ARG PHP_XDEBUG_VERSION
ENV PHP_ZLIB_DIR=/usr/

# Fix timezone issue
ENV TZ=Europe/Lisbon
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone \
    ; \
    apk upgrade --update-cache --available && \
    apk add --update --no-cache \
    autoconf bash g++ coreutils gcc make git openssh-client \
    libressl-dev patch pkgconfig subversion tini \
    #dep for php ext: gettext
    gettext-dev \
    #dep for php ext: bz2
    bzip2-dev \
    #dep for php ext: xsl + soap
    libxslt-dev \
    #dep for php ext: mongodb
    mongodb-tools \
    #dep for php ext: msgpack
    msgpack-c  \
    #dep for php ext: zip
    unzip zip \
    ; \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
    #dep for php ext: intl 
    icu-dev \
    ; \
    docker-php-source extract \
    # && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
    bcmath \
    bz2 \
    calendar  \
    exif \ 
    gettext \
    intl \
    # process control ?
    # pcntl \
    pdo_mysql \
    # shared memory ?
    # shmop \
    soap \
    sockets \
    # WDDX ?
    # wddx \
    xsl \
    zip \
    ; \
    pecl channel-update pecl.php.net \
    && pecl install igbinary \
    && pecl install msgpack \
    && pecl install mongodb-1.10.0 \
    && echo "php_ini = /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && pecl install ${PHP_XDEBUG_VERSION} \
    #dep for php ext: yaml
    && apk add --update --no-cache yaml-dev \
    && pecl install yaml \
    #dep for php ext: memcached
    && apk add --update --no-cache libmemcached-dev zlib-dev libpng-dev \
    && pecl install memcached --with-zlib-dir=$PHP_ZLIB_DIR \
    # && echo "extension=memcached.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/memcached.ini \
    #dep for php ext: rabbitmq / amqp
    && apk add --update --no-cache rabbitmq-c-dev \
    && printf "\n" | pecl install ${AMQP_VERSION} \
    && printf "\n" | pecl install redis-5.3.2 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable igbinary msgpack mongodb xdebug yaml memcached redis \
    # enabling amqp ext this way avoids coflicts loading dependecies  (sockets)
    && echo "extension=amqp" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/40-amqp.ini \
    # && pecl bundle redis \
    # && docker-php-ext-configure redis --enable-redis-igbinary \
    # && docker-php-ext-install redis \
    && docker-php-source delete \
    && apk del --purge .build-deps \
    && mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-production" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"

## Composer
ARG COMPOSER_IMAGE
FROM ${COMPOSER_IMAGE} AS composer


FROM php AS phalcon
ARG PHP_PHALCON_VERSION
#phalcon
RUN cd ~ && git clone --depth=1 -b ${PHP_PHALCON_VERSION} git://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git \
    && cd ~/cphalcon/build \
    && ./install \
    && echo "extension=phalcon.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/50-phalcon.ini \
    && rm -rf ~/cphalcon \
    ; \
    # clean up
    apk del autoconf bash check-dev cyrus-sasl-dev g++ gcc \
    imagemagick-dev libc-dev libssh2-dev libsodium-dev \
    m4 make musl-dev openssl-dev perl pkgconfig \
    tzdata \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* && rm -rf /tmp/*
# RUN php -r "echo Phalcon\Version::get();"
COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
WORKDIR /app


You can skip the requirements check by creating the file /tmp/vscode-skip-server-requirements-check, see the start of the check-requirements-linux.sh script.
But as the error message tells you the version of alpine you used is not supported by vscode, see https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/linux: vscode requires alpine 3.16+ with musl >= 1.2.3
The image you use - php:7.2-fpm-alpine3.12 - is based on alpine 3.12 which uses musl 1.1.24.
So you could skip the check but would then most probably run into other issues afterwards.
Instead you should use a base image with a supported alpine version, e.g., php:7.4-fpm-alpine, or if no appropriate image is available on the docker registry build your own from scratch.

Thank you for your response @acran! Though I didn't quite understand how I would implement it. Do I create a folder tmp, then the vscode-skip-server-requirements-check with the check-requirements-linux.sh file inside it? Could you maybe show be how it can be achieved in a practical way if you don't mind :)

The file needs to exist inside the dev container before vscode runs the requirements check in it. So the easiest way would be to just put it in the image with RUN touch /tmp/vscode-skip-server-requirements-check. BUT - as I said above - this will only skip the check and won't make the incompatibilities go away. So it will probably break later on anayway still^^

@sirvictahh did you change your image alpine version? I use python:3.9-alpine3.13 and I'm facing the same issue. I want to attach a dev container to a running container.

@lator I ended up dropping the image I was using yeah. If the workaround I've detailed about downgrading the VS Code version works for you, and isn't any type of security risk, I recommend doing just that, then, you can use the image you we're trying to use, and don't loose much on VS Code's functionalities.

@sirvictahh This is such a bummer. I can't change the image -it's not a personal project.
I tried to use VS Code 1.85.0 in portable mode as you said and in an answer I found, but the problem is the same. The last resort will be to change the image distro to something else that is compatible.
